# MySQLi Un-prepare-d

Tags: php, mysqli

I am converting my old mysql_* queries over to mysqli except i'm having a frustrating issue

```
$st = $this->Sql->prepare("INSERT INTO tblPlayerOnline (SteamID,PlayerName,IPAddress,ConnectedDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)") or die($this->Sql->error);
/* 225 */ $st->bind_param("i", $SteamID);
$st->bind_param("ssi", $PlayerName, $IPAddress, $TimeNow);
$st->execute();
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home/vanrust/public_html/rework/class/Players.class.php on line 225

But when I dump `$this->Sql` I get  `object(mysqli)#2 (19) { bla bla`  so not sure what this error is telling me.

Dump of `$this->Sql` http://pastebin.com/gdKAgT4D

Any guidance is appreciated!

PS Looked Everywhere -.-

Comment: fyi, you don't need multiple invocations of `bind_param`, it already supports multiple parameters for you to put into it. add an `or die($this->Sql->error)` in the prepare line

Comment: hello, I'd show you a git revision of me doing that originally but its a private repo lol :(( error is empty, errno is 0

Comment: hm, `Open tables: 400`, is this a normal number or is it a max level of sorts depicting my large lack of `$st->close`'s that I have around

Comment: `$st` isn't an object because `prepare` returned `FALSE`.

Comment: can you show us how you created `$this->Sql` ?

Comment: `var_dump($this->Sql); die;` before line 225?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Uf2Tpmza

Comment: `$st` is most probably `false`, which means the statement could not be prepared. It is likely that you have a typo in your SQL query, maybe the name of the table or a column is wrong.

Comment: if all else fails, use PDO. I recommend it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this frustrated me for awhile but I found the answer was in front of me all along right there in `$this->Sql->stat` - Oddly, 400 open tables seemed like a rather nice even number however this was clearly a maximum.

I tracked back through my code and began adding `$st->close()` to everything and this fixed this problem for me.

So lesson learned; close it once you're done with it

Thanks to all for helping

Answer (score 1):

When the `prepare` statement fails and no `mysqli_prepare` object is returned, there's a big chance you have an error inside your query.. or something worse.

For debugging purposes you can use the `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL)` function (which is an alias for `mysqli_driver->report_mode`). This can give you some more information why the `prepare` is failing and be helpfull for debugging.

Place the following in the beginning of your code

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);

//Or if you just want an exception when Mysqli has an error? 
//Set the reporting level to 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Next to that I think it's very risky to always assume that the `mysql_prepare` object is returned. You should first check before using it:

```
if ($stmt = $this->Sql->prepare(....)) {
    //Yep, we can now start binding parameters
} else {
    //Noooooo.. got error?
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Looks like `$st` is null, meaning that the statement failed to prepare.

Try to see what's causing it with this:

```
if (!$st) {
     echo "Prepare failed: (" . $this->Sql->errno . ") " . $this->Sql->error;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, the response I get is `Prepare failed: (0) `